# Optimizing Google Apps Script to Collapse Groups in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recorded a Macro on Google Sheets to have a button expand all selected groups. However, it takes a few seconds for the script to run, and I would prefer it to be instantaneous. Is there a way to make the script quicker?

`

```
function ExpandAll() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
  ss.getColumnGroup(12, 1).expand();
  ss.getColumnGroup(19, 1).expand();
  ss.getColumnGroup(30, 1).expand();
  ss.getColumnGroup(39, 1).expand();
  ss.getColumnGroup(59, 1).expand();
  ss.getColumnGroup(62, 1).expand();
};
```

`

I've looked up that calling the sheet might slow down the script, but I am not sure how to do this any other way.

Comment: I think that when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced. But, in this case, in order to achieve your goal with one API call, it is required to know the correct columns and the number of columns of each group of your groups, and it is required to include all groups you want to manage. How about this? I'm not sure whether this is your expected direction. So, first, I commented on it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your expectation of instantaneous expansion may be unrealistic. Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand *all* groups with a single call, like this:

```
function expandAllGroups() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().expandAllColumnGroups();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand all:

```
function ExpandAll() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
  [12,19,39,59,62].forEach(r => sh.getColumnGroup(r,1).expand())
};
```